# LLDB set breakpoint at memory address

Tags: memory-address, lldb, ida

I have opened an executable in IDA Pro, and found the location I want to break at, 0x3390 from the beginning of the file.

How do I set a breakpoint in lldb at the memory address, start of program + 0x3390.

I tried `b s -a 0x3390` but it doesn't work, I presume because I need the actual address, not the offset.

Answer (score 5):

The `image list` command will show the load address of the __TEXT.__text section of all the executables loaded in the program.  If you need more information, `image dump sections` will dump the addresses of all the sections.  From this you should be able to figure out what to offset your address with.  Note that the program may not load at its pre-run address, so you may have to figure out the base address after you've started up.

Then you should be able to say:

```
(lldb) br set -a <FileAddress>+<Address>
```

Note, `b` is an alias for some fancy regular-expression based command that tries to emulate the gdb breakpoint expression parser, so you either need to disable that alias or use `br` to get the full breakpoint command.